# Concatenate Db Field with $_POST variables php / mysql

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication

**HTML**

```
  <form style="margin:5px 0;" action="#" method="post"> 
                Buyer <input type="radio" name="addType" value="Buyer" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;Merchant <input type="radio" name="addType" value="Merchant" />
            </form>
            <form id="NewBuyerRegHp" method="post" action="check.php">
                Username or Email: <input type="text" name="userOrEmail" class="UserLogin" value="Username" onFocus="clearText(this)" /> <br />
                Password: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" name="userPass" class="UserLogin" value="Password" onFocus="clearText(this)"  /> <br />
                <input type="submit" name="SubmitNewBuyerHp" value="Secure Login" />
            </form>
```

**PHP**

```
require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');

$entPass =  $_POST['userPass']; #entered password by user.
$SaltyPass = hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$escapedInputtedPass); #more secure pass with dynam salt using SHA512 Hashing

$NewUserLoginCheck = mysql_query("SELECT uUName, uEmail, uUPass, dynamSalt FROM User WHERE uUName OR  uEmail = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userOrEmail'])."' AND uUPass = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass'])."'    ")or die(mysql_error());
```

How do I concatenate the inputted user pass with  `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass'])` with the `dynamSalt` field?? I want to combination of `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass']) . dynamSalt` but I can't use the dynamSalt until its accessed in the SQL statement?

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: There's no need to escape user input before hashing it.

Comment: Also, the description of your problem is completely unclear; I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I want to concatenate the `userPass` with the field name `dynamSalt` to check that a valid username is given... this concatentation of `userPass.dynamSalt` with validate the password. Following me now?

Comment: It is an aside, but whilst we are talking about security, it is bad practice to use string concatenation to build SQL queries. There are some exploits that can get through the string escaping function `mysql_real_escape_string` (and it never works on data not delimited by single-quotes). Consider creating queries with bound parameters, using the PDO or Mysqli libraries instead; These cannot be fooled into being vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');

//$entPass =  $_POST['userPass']; #entered password by user.
//$SaltyPass = hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$escapedInputtedPass); #more secure pass with dynam salt using SHA512 Hashing

$NewUserLoginCheck = mysql_query("SELECT uUName, uEmail, uUPass, dynamSalt FROM User WHERE uUName OR  uEmail = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userOrEmail'])."' AND uUPass = sha2(concat(dynamSalt, '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass'])."'), 512)    ")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Its originally hashed in sha 512 though. How do I implement that?

Comment: It is originally hashed and salted into the db using: `hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$escapedInputtedPass)`

Comment: ok then change 256 to 512
`$NewUserLoginCheck = mysql_query("SELECT uUName, uEmail, uUPass, dynamSalt FROM User WHERE uUName OR  uEmail = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userOrEmail'])."' AND uUPass = sha2(concat(dynamSalt, '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass'])."'), 512)    ")or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: so its literally changing: `($_POST['userPass'])."'), 256)` to `($_POST['userPass'])."'), 512)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I personally am not a fan of concat or escaping strings in the middle of a query.  If possible it is best (imo) to do everything pre-query.  That way your query is easily readable, and your can perform more checks on the user input easier like running through functions and such.